# unity fix orientation in an axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a first person rigidbody capsule that rotates so that he will always be upright against the gravity direction. I want to rotate my player to the side so that the player camera will not rotate vertically.

My code is,

```
void Update() {
    FixOrientation();
}

void FixOrientation()
{
    if (trans.up != -GetGravityDirection())
    {
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(trans.up, -GetGravityDirection()) * trans.localRotation;
        trans.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(trans.localRotation, targetRotation, 5f);
    }
}
```

The result is,
[image: current]

In the image above, I changed the gravity direction to point to the ceiling.

This code only rotates the player at the global x-axis no matter where he is facing which means when i'm facing global forward or backward, the player will rotate vertically the camera. What I want is for it to rotate on the side(local z axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity already has a method for exactly that: [`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) has an overload taking an angle and a rotation axis.

It might look like

```
// rotation speed in degrees per second
public float RotationSpeed;

void Update()
{
    FixOrientation();
}

void FixOrientation()
{
    if (transform.up != -GetGravityDirection())
    {
        // Get the current angle between the up axis and your negative gravity vector
        var difference = Vector3.Angle(transform.up, -GetGravityDirection());

        // This simply assures you don't overshoot and rotate more than required 
        // to avoid a back-forward loop
        // also use Time.deltaTime for a frame-independent rotation speed
        var maxStep = Mathf.Min(difference, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // you only want ot rotate around local Z axis
        // Space.Self makes sure you use the local axis
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, maxStep, Space.Self);
        }
    }
```

---

A Sidenote:

Just in general be careful with the direct comparison of two Vectors

```
trans.up != -GetGravityDirection()
```

uses an approximation of `0.00001`. In your case that should be fine anyway but for comparing  you should rather use

```
Vector3.Angle(vector1, vector2) > threshold
```

to define a wider or stronger threshold

Comment: i still have the problem regarding the first person camera that can rotate the player on y-axis which if used while applying FixOrientation() produces undesired looping rotation nevertheless this sufficed to answer the question thanks.

Comment: Glad that it helps you! I also just noted that somehow it still might overshoot resulting in a "flickering" when the direction is not exactly `Vector3.up` or `-Vector3.up`.  But it's strange that it behaves different if changing the y-axis meanwhile but might come from how the difference is calculated